# Refresh grid after removing records from local store

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, refresh

I have a ext js grid with pagination, store is of type pagingmemory.
But when I remove the record from grid, it does not get removed. Also the toolbar does not reflect the count and page number correctly.

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Model',
    autoLoad: false,
    buffered: false,
    pageSize: 5,
    data:[],
    proxy: {
        type: 'pagingmemory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'somedata'
        }
    }

});


 var myGrid =  new Ext.grid.Panel({

.....
 ,bbar:new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                        store:myStore,
                        id:'mtoolbar',
                        pageSize: 5,
                        displayInfo: true,
                        height: 25,
                        displayMsg:'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                        emptyMsg: "No records to display",
```

The button has handler that remove that remove the record from store

```
store.remove(selectedItems);
Ext.getCmp('clientSummaryGridId').getView().refresh();
```

But this does not refresh the grid and pagination does not get reflected. Pls advice.

Comment: pls ignore any mismatch as i this is not exact code.

Comment: Have you tried to `sync()` the store associated with grid?

Comment: if(selectedItems.length>0)
              {
            
               var store=Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore();
               store.remove(selectedItems);
              
              
              // store.totalCount = store.count();

               Ext.getCmp('btoolbar').onLoad();
 
               Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getView().refresh();

                }
                
            }
            }]